# Add permanent security exception to localhost for chrome

Tags: security, google-chrome, https, localhost

What is the procedure to add a security exception for Chrome on localhost?

I tried to follow the instructions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15076602/4471086) post but it doesn't seem to work.

Suggestions?

The Chrome version  is the following 39.0.2171.99 m.